# Automatically kill processes that over time uses 95%+ of resources? Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, process

I don't know about your computer but when mine is working properly no process is sucking 95%+ over time. I would like to have some failsafe that kills any processes behaving like that. This comes to mind because when I woke up this morning my laptop had been crunching all night long on a stray chromium child process.

This can probably be done as a cron job, but before I make it a full time job creating something like this I'd thought I should check here. :) I hate reinventing the wheel.

Comment: This is for sure possible (using `ps` and similar tools). But the real question is, do you really want that? Check-Programs of all kind can grind pretty high cpu usage for quiet some time, also image-processing can take that, too. You should ask yourself a question: Is it worth the aftermath *if* it kills the wrong process?

Comment: You almost always should fix the underlying problem. It's not really a good idea to blindly kill processes based on their resource usage. That's what the kernel's [OOM-killer](http://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer) is for (at least for memory).

Comment: I'd also have to argue against doing it with any kind of auto-kill script/job.  Maybe auto-notify is the right way and you can decide to kill or not.  Fix underlying problem once it's identified.  If your computer can send email to your phone then you can do this "real-time" or close enough.

Comment: many makefile compile source code with `make $(nproc)`, this will take up to approx. 100% cpu usage most of the time, and it should not be killed. I would recommend you to investigate the root cause and see what takes up so much resources, then find a way to stop/remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Others have encountered this problem, and while there doesn't seem to be any prevention mechanisms builtin to Ubuntu, there are some [ideas](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/11628) about how to improve this.

There's a similar [Serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/97541/kill-process-with-high-cpu-usage-after-x-time) that mentions [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) might be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a script, [kill-process](https://github.com/padosoft/kill-process), that kills some processes listed in an array, if CPU usage is greater than XX% for YY seconds or kill processes that's running more than ZZ seconds.

- You can set XX, YY, ZZ in the top of the file.
- You can use a ps or top for check processes.
- There's a dry run mode too, to check but not kill.
- In the end, the script sends an email if some processes were killed.

**NOTE:** Here is my repo on Github: https://github.com/padosoft/kill-process

#### Essential part of script (a code abstract for top command):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#max cpu % load
MAX_CPU=90
#max execution time for CPU percentage > MAX_CPU (in seconds 7200s=2h)
MAX_SEC=1800
#sort by cpu
SORTBY=9

#define a processes command name to check
declare -a KILLLIST
KILLLIST=("/usr/sbin/apache2" "/usr/bin/php5-cgi")

#iterate for each process to check in list
for PROCESS_TOCHECK in ${KILLLIST[*]}
do

    #retrive pid with top command order by SORTBY
    PID=$(top -bcSH -n 1 | grep $PROCESS_TOCHECK | sort -k $SORTBY -r | head -n 1 | awk '{print $1}')

    CPU=$(top -p $PID -bcSH -n 1 | grep $PROCESS_TOCHECK | sort -k $SORTBY -r | head -n 1 | awk '{print $9}')
    TIME_STR=$(top -p $PID -bcSH -n 1 | grep $PROCESS_TOCHECK | sort -k $SORTBY -r | head -n 1 | awk '{print $11}')

    # Decode the top CPU time format [dd-]hh:mm.ss.
    TIME_SEC=0
    IFS="-:" read c1 c2 c3 c4 <<< "$TIME_STR"

    #with top command time format is hh:mm.ss, so truncare seconds in c2
    c2=${c2%%.*}

    if [ -n "$c4" ]
    then
      TIME_SEC=$((10#$c4+60*(10#$c3+60*(10#$c2+24*10#$c1))))
    elif [ -n "$c3" ]
    then
      if [ "$CMD" = "ps" ]; then
        TIME_SEC=$((10#$c3+60*(10#$c2+60*10#$c1)))
      else
        TIME_SEC=$(((10#$c3*24)*60*60)+60*(10#$c2+60*10#$c1))             
      fi   
    else
      if [ "$CMD" = "ps" ]; then
        TIME_SEC=$((10#0+(10#$c2+60*10#$c1)))
      else
        TIME_SEC=$((10#0+60*(10#$c2+60*10#$c1)))
      fi
    fi

    #check if need to kill process
    if [ $CPU -gt $MAX_CPU ] && [ $TIME_SEC -gt $MAX_SEC ]; then
        kill -15 $PID
    fi

done
```

Usage:

```
bash killprocess.sh [dry|kill|--help] [top|ps] [cpu|time]
```

Comment: @DavidPostill I add an abstract of script code. Thank's.

Comment: Much better ... :)

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I made a script for my University classes, that was controlling system resources (CPU and/or RAM) usage. You can easily changed maximum prohibited usage by editing variables at the  script start. 
Script should be started in backgroung like that:

```
nohup ./auto_killer.sh &
```

Script is looking for processes that use too much resources every N seconds. If some process use too much of resources, the user that runs it get warning message on his console. If same process is spoted 2 times in row, it gets killed (And user gets info about it).

Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

Check_Repeating_Time=3; # in seconds
Max_CPU_Usage='25.0'; #%
Max_RAM_Usage='2.0'; #%
Log_Path='/var/log/auto_killer_log'; # path to file when killing logs will be writed

while [ 1 ]; do

    ps -aux | 
    awk '{
        Username = $1;
        Proc_Name = $11;
        CPU_Usage = $3;
        RAM_Usage = $4;
        PID = $2;
        TTY = $7;

        if((CPU_Usage >= '$Max_CPU_Usage' || RAM_Usage >= '$Max_RAM_Usage' ) &&  !($1 == "USER" || $1 == "root" || $1 == "daemon" || $1 == "mysql" || $1 == "avahi" || $1 == "polkitd"))
        {
            Func_Num_of_Ocur = "cat ./auto_killer_data | grep "PID" | wc -l";
            Func_Num_of_Ocur |getline Str_Num_Of_Ocur;              

            if(Str_Num_Of_Ocur == "0")
            {
                system ("echo \"\" >> /dev/" TTY);
                system ("echo \"Process "Proc_Name" used to much of resources. It will be killed in '$Check_Repeating_Time' seconds if it wont stop!\" >> /dev/" TTY );
                system ("echo \"\" >> /dev/" TTY);
                system ("echo "PID" >> ./auto_killer_data.new");
            }
            else
            {
                system ("echo \"\" >> /dev/" TTY);
                system ("echo \"Process "Proc_Name" was killed because it used to much of system resources!\" >> /dev/" TTY );
                system ("echo \"\" >> /dev/" TTY);
                system ("kill -9 " PID);
                Data = "date";
                Data |getline Str_Data;
                system ("echo \""Str_Data"  "Username"  "Proc_Name" "TTY"\" >> '$Log_Path'");
            }
        }
    }';

    if [ -e ./auto_killer_data.new ]; then
        mv ./auto_killer_data.new ./auto_killer_data
    else    
        echo '' > ./auto_killer_data
    fi

    #We wait fo a while and repeate process
    sleep $Check_Repeating_Time\s;
done;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the similar issue before, and here is the small piece of python code to solve it:

[Link to github repository](https://github.com/minhhn2910/process-monitor)